# Cancel a toast on Android before it appears

Tags: android, toast

My application displays a `Toast` when a certain action happens. If two of these actions happen in close proximity, however, I would like to forgo displaying the first `Toast`, instead displaying only the second one. I thought `Toast.cancel()` would do the trick, but what it does is simply hide the first toast; the second one only displays after the first one would have finished displaying anyway.

Example code:

```
Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Test1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "Test2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

toast1.show();
toast2.show();

toast1.cancel();
```

The second `Toast` shows up only after waiting a short while (the length of the short duration). This in fact happens even if I call `toast2.cancel()`.

Comment: I have had good results from [my `Boast.java` class referenced in this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098151/android-cancel-toast-when-exiting-the-app-and-when-toast-is-being-shown). I've not had a problem with `.cancel()` not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would work, but maybe try cancelling both of them and then showing the second one again.

Comment: Sorry, same result: Test2 appears but is delayed. I actually found that in the Toast source code, the only thing "cancel" does is hides the view, not dequeue the toast in the system.

Answer (score 1):

`Toast.makeText(context, text, duration)` returns a **Toast** object. Call **cancel()** method on this object to cancel it.

Example:

```
Toast mToastText = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello StackOverFlow!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 mToastText.cancel();
```

Comment: Did you even read his question?