# Cancel currently showing toast due to some other app in android

Tags: android, android-toast

Title seems duplicate question but its not, trust me.

I want to cancel the `toast` currently showing on the screen due to some other service (I can not get toast object so can not call `toast.cancel()` ).

Is there any way to get info about currently showing toast on screen due to any other app/service and then cancel it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many many thanks in advance.

Comment: i would like to add an example for more clarity. Lets say I am running APP 'A'. i do some operation which invoke Service 'B' to display toast on screen. Now I want to immediately cancel that toast. Is there any way to get Toast object currently being shown on screen regardless of which app/service displayed that toast.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this. However you could use a wrapper class for Toast to keep the reference for you. This was proposed by @[Richard Le Mesurier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383414/richard-le-mesurier) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099959/1756721). All credits go to him.

You basically can replace **Toast** with **Boast**.

---

```
package com.mobiRic.ui.widget;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * {@link Toast} decorator allowing for easy cancellation of notifications. Use
 * this class if you want subsequent Toast notifications to overwrite current
 * ones. </p>
 * 
 * By default, a current {@link Boast} notification will be cancelled by a
 * subsequent notification. This default behaviour can be changed by calling
 * certain methods like {@link #show(boolean)}.
 */
public class Boast
{
    /**
     * Keeps track of certain {@link Boast} notifications that may need to be cancelled.
     * This functionality is only offered by some of the methods in this class.
     */
    private volatile static Boast globalBoast = null;

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Internal reference to the {@link Toast} object that will be displayed.
     */
    private Toast internalToast;

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Private constructor creates a new {@link Boast} from a given
     * {@link Toast}.
     * 
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *         if the parameter is <code>null</code>.
     */
    private Boast(Toast toast)
    {
        // null check
        if (toast == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException(
                "Boast.Boast(Toast) requires a non-null parameter.");
        }

        internalToast = toast;
    }

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Make a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param text
     *        The text to show. Can be formatted text.
     * @param duration
     *        How long to display the message. Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
     *        {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
     */
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public static Boast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text,
        int duration)
    {
        return new Boast(Toast.makeText(context, text, duration));
    }

    /**
     * Make a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view with the
     * text from a resource.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param resId
     *        The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted
     *        text.
     * @param duration
     *        How long to display the message. Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
     *        {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
     * 
     * @throws Resources.NotFoundException
     *         if the resource can't be found.
     */
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public static Boast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
        throws Resources.NotFoundException
    {
        return new Boast(Toast.makeText(context, resId, duration));
    }

    /**
     * Make a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view. Duration
     * defaults to {@link #LENGTH_SHORT}.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param text
     *        The text to show. Can be formatted text.
     */
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public static Boast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text)
    {
        return new Boast(Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT));
    }

    /**
     * Make a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view with the
     * text from a resource. Duration defaults to {@link #LENGTH_SHORT}.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param resId
     *        The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted
     *        text.
     * 
     * @throws Resources.NotFoundException
     *         if the resource can't be found.
     */
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    public static Boast makeText(Context context, int resId)
        throws Resources.NotFoundException
    {
        return new Boast(Toast.makeText(context, resId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT));
    }

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Show a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param text
     *        The text to show. Can be formatted text.
     * @param duration
     *        How long to display the message. Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
     *        {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
     */
    public static void showText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
    {
        Boast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view with the
     * text from a resource.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param resId
     *        The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted
     *        text.
     * @param duration
     *        How long to display the message. Either {@link #LENGTH_SHORT} or
     *        {@link #LENGTH_LONG}
     * 
     * @throws Resources.NotFoundException
     *         if the resource can't be found.
     */
    public static void showText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
        throws Resources.NotFoundException
    {
        Boast.makeText(context, resId, duration).show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view. Duration
     * defaults to {@link #LENGTH_SHORT}.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param text
     *        The text to show. Can be formatted text.
     */
    public static void showText(Context context, CharSequence text)
    {
        Boast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**
     * Show a standard {@link Boast} that just contains a text view with the
     * text from a resource. Duration defaults to {@link #LENGTH_SHORT}.
     * 
     * @param context
     *        The context to use. Usually your {@link android.app.Application}
     *        or {@link android.app.Activity} object.
     * @param resId
     *        The resource id of the string resource to use. Can be formatted
     *        text.
     * 
     * @throws Resources.NotFoundException
     *         if the resource can't be found.
     */
    public static void showText(Context context, int resId)
        throws Resources.NotFoundException
    {
        Boast.makeText(context, resId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet.
     * You do not normally have to call this. Normally view will disappear on
     * its own after the appropriate duration.
     */
    public void cancel()
    {
        internalToast.cancel();
    }

    /**
     * Show the view for the specified duration. By default, this method cancels
     * any current notification to immediately display the new one. For
     * conventional {@link Toast#show()} queueing behaviour, use method
     * {@link #show(boolean)}.
     * 
     * @see #show(boolean)
     */
    public void show()
    {
        show(true);
    }

    /**
     * Show the view for the specified duration. This method can be used to
     * cancel the current notification, or to queue up notifications.
     * 
     * @param cancelCurrent
     *        <code>true</code> to cancel any current notification and replace
     *        it with this new one
     * 
     * @see #show()
     */
    public void show(boolean cancelCurrent)
    {
        // cancel current
        if (cancelCurrent && (globalBoast != null))
        {
            globalBoast.cancel();
        }

        // save an instance of this current notification
        globalBoast = this;

        internalToast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: hi qmar! Thanks for replying. Its alright. I am already using this concept though in my own way of course. But this thing can keep track only of my own toasts. But I want to get information of other toasts too. But this does not seem possible to get  toast object of currently showing toast on the screen due to some other app.

Comment: I've also looked on the sources: tried to get the message by using findById(), and also getting it by the internal service. No success though. I guess there is an ultra hacky way using reflection but I wouldn't recommend that, because the internal implementation can always change.